# Python elastic search query returns twice of data in elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Below is my es query body, its just match_all and sort via unique index number

```
body = {
    "size": 1,
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "index_number .numeric": {
                "order": "asc"
            }
        }
    ]

}
```

And the below is process_hits function in python. It just printing the doc.

```
 process_hits():
        for doc in hits:
            print (doc)
```

And the below is my es connection and scroll api code.

```
es = Elasticsearch(
        [
            {
                'host': host,
                'port': port
            }
        ],
        timeout=timeout
    )
    # Check index exists
    if not es.indices.exists(index=index):
        print("Index " + index + " not exists")
        exit()

    # Init scroll by search
    data = es.search(
        index=index,
        scroll='2m',
        size=1,
        body=body
    )

    # Get the scroll ID
    sid = data['_scroll_id']
    scroll_size = len(data['hits']['hits'])
    line_number = []
    while scroll_size > 0:
        "Scrolling..."

        # Before scroll, process current batch of hits
        process_hits(data['hits']['hits'])

        data = es.scroll(scroll_id=sid, scroll='2m')

        # Update the scroll ID
        sid = data['_scroll_id']

        # Get the number of results that returned in the last scroll
        scroll_size = len(data['hits']['hits'])
```

When I run my search query in kibana devtools. I get perfect result. But in python rest client. I get twice of data. As shown index_numbers of datas are in below picture.

[image]

I think its about the scrolling. Below picture shows there are 4 scroll size then 0, and again 4-0. I think it is scrolling same scroll id but i didn't find a way

[image]

Thanks for answering.

Comment: Can you add your entire scrolling code?

Comment: Are you sure you want `size: 1`? What's the idea to scroll documents one at a time?

Comment: There was an error when i made 100. My index has less than 100 docs. I ve changed the batch size, after that i was able to receive it so i did it.  I don't have logic behind there.

Comment: Even if you have less than 100 docs, you can use size 100... What was the error ?

Comment: I don't remember what was the error but you are right. I have just changed it and not getting error. Probably, this error was about something else, that i didn't configured out. But changing the batch size didn't solve the question cause i still have duplicate values.

Comment: What do you do in `process_hits`?

Comment: for doc in hits: print(json.dumps(doc['_source']["index_number"]))

Comment: Just print the index number. I use json.dumps for escaping unicode characters (like u')

Comment: I have solved my question. The problem was about python class. Thanks for your help @Val

Comment: Cool, glad you figured it out